# OpenJdk 11 in AIX 7.1 cannot load module libfontmanager.so

Tags: java, aix, lib, automic

I have configured OpenJdk 11 in my AIX 7.1 Server and I'm trying to run one of the jar file. However I'm getting the below error and the jar file is getting aborted. But I can see the libfontmanager.so file in my lib folder. I have also added the new jdk path in LIBPATH & LD_LIBRARY_PATH and PATH variables. It is showing about some libfreetype.so.6 but I'm not sure if it's an internal module of libfontmanager.so or I need to install it separately.

> **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:**
> **/usr/jdk11/lib/libfontmanager.so: /usr/jdk11/lib/libfontmanager.so**,
> LIBPATH=/usr/jdk11/lib/server:/usr/jdk11/lib:/usr/jdk11/lib/jli:/usr/jdk11/../lib:.:/appli/automic/21/Utility/bin:/appli/automic/instantclient_12_1:/usr/lib:/lib:/usr/jdk11/lib,
> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/appli/automic/21/Utility/bin:/appli/automic/instantclient_12_1:/usr/lib:/lib:/usr/jdk11/lib
> :       **0509-022 Cannot load module /usr/jdk11/lib/libfontmanager.so**.
> **0509-150   Dependent module libfreetype.a(libfreetype.so.6) could not be loaded.**
> **0509-022 Cannot load module libfreetype.a(libfreetype.so.6).**
> **0509-026 System error: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.**
> **0509-022 Cannot load module /usr/jdk11/lib/libfontmanager.so.**
> **0509-150   Dependent module /usr/jdk11/lib/libfontmanager.so could not be loaded.**
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(ClassLoader.java:2445)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2501)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:2700)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2651)
> at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830)
> at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1873)
> at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerNativeLibrary$1.run(FontManagerNativeLibrary.java:57)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerNativeLibrary.(FontManagerNativeLibrary.java:32)
> at java.desktop/sun.java2d.xr.XRSurfaceData.initXRSurfaceData(XRSurfaceData.java:104)
> at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:124)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:61)
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment$LocalGE.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:101)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment$LocalGE.(GraphicsEnvironment.java:83)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:129)
> at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.(XToolkit.java:232)
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:588)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:583)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:582)
> at java.desktop/sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.getSystemMnemonicKeyMask(SwingUtilities2.java:2212)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLookAndFeel.initComponentDefaults(BasicLookAndFeel.java:1096)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel.initComponentDefaults(MetalLookAndFeel.java:440)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLookAndFeel.getDefaults(BasicLookAndFeel.java:150)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel.getDefaults(MetalLookAndFeel.java:1560)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:587)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:629)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.UIManager.initializeDefaultLAF(UIManager.java:1404)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.UIManager.initialize(UIManager.java:1517)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.UIManager.maybeInitialize(UIManager.java:1483)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.UIManager.getDefaults(UIManager.java:709)
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.UIManager.put(UIManager.java:1038)
> at com.ucutil.ucdbload.CUCYDBLoad.licence(CUCYDBLoad.java:231)
> at com.ucutil.ucdbload.CUCYDBLoad.(CUCYDBLoad.java:118)
> at com.ucutil.ucdbload.CUCYDBLoad.main(CUCYDBLoad.java:958)

Comment: The problem could be related to headless OpenJDK, UI libraries are not included in headless JDK  versions.

Comment: You might want to install `freetype`. Try command `yum install freetype2` as root user.